# saving Spark files to S3 using presigned URL

Tags: java, apache-spark

I'm trying to use Spark to save large datasets to S3, the problem is that I do not have access and secret keys of S3, I can only use presigned URL to save data to S3.
is there any way to do it?

Comment: I thought "presigned URLs" were meant to _read a single object_, not to _write multiple objects in a "directory"_...

Comment: presigned URLs can be used to upload also, however; it has to be 1 object per url: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html